# substr works strangely with dashes in the string

Tags: php, string

I have the following three cases which I would expect to display the same output, but it does something strange for `$str1`:

```
<?php
$str1 = "— lorem lorem Alice lorem lorem lorem loremlorem";
//       | < Why would a dash make a difference in the the found index?
$str2 = "a lorem lorem Alice lorem lorem lorem loremlorem";
$str3 = "  lorem lorem Alice lorem lorem lorem loremlorem";


// The found index is always the same
$foundIndex = mb_stripos($str1, "Alice"); 
var_dump(substr($str1, $foundIndex - 6, 24), $foundIndex);

$foundIndex = mb_stripos($str2, "Alice");
var_dump(substr($str2, $foundIndex - 6, 24), $foundIndex);

$foundIndex = mb_stripos($str3, "Alice");
var_dump(substr($str3, $foundIndex - 6, 24), $foundIndex);
```

**Output**:

```
string(24) "m lorem Alice lorem lore"     << Why is this swapped to the right one char?
int(14)
string(24) "lorem Alice lorem lorem "
int(14)
string(24) "lorem Alice lorem lorem "
int(14)
```

You can test it [**here**](https://3v4l.org/alaWY).

I use the operations `mb_stripos` and `substr` for searching in strings and this is the PoC.

Why is this and how can I fix the behaviour for strings containing special characters?

---

From a quick check, I think `—` occupies three bytes, and `substr` works by bytes, not by *characters*. `strlen("—")` is `3` too...

How can I slice the string by characters, instead of by bytes? Slicing it by bytes won't really work for me. And all the special characters should be handled correctly. If I am not wrong emojis, have different sizes too!

Comment: What character is that exactly? It's not `-`, but larger/wider. The dash on my keyboard works fine.

Comment: It's an [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Comment: @Daan Yes, it's an em dash, but I think this current implementation is breaking for any special character that has more bytes.

Comment: You'll need to use `mb_substr()`. It performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of characters

Comment: @Daan Yes, that worked indeed! Please post an answer. :-)

Comment: Great, posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The em dash you're using is a multibyte character. To perform a multi-byte safe substr() operation, you need to use `mb_substr()`.

```
<?php
$str1 = "— lorem lorem Alice lorem lorem lorem loremlorem";
//       | < Why would a dash make a difference in the the found index?
$str2 = "a lorem lorem Alice lorem lorem lorem loremlorem";
$str3 = "  lorem lorem Alice lorem lorem lorem loremlorem";


// The found index is always the same
$foundIndex = mb_stripos($str1, "Alice"); 
var_dump(mb_substr($str1, $foundIndex - 6, 24), $foundIndex);

$foundIndex = mb_stripos($str2, "Alice");
var_dump(mb_substr($str2, $foundIndex - 6, 24), $foundIndex);

$foundIndex = mb_stripos($str3, "Alice");
var_dump(mb_substr($str3, $foundIndex - 6, 24), $foundIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

```
echo strlen('-') . "\n";  // equals 1 using a normal dash
echo strlen('—') . "\n";   // equals 3 using your "em dash"
```

So if u do `echo substr($str1, 0, 3) . "\n";` you get your "em dash".